# С прописной или строчной писать "ваш" в рекламном сообщении?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В рекламном обращении "Соберем ваш дом" "ваш" писать с маленькой буквы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В рекламных листовках "Ваш" пишется с большой буквы (обращение к неконкретному лицу).
Цитата [из справочника Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=93#pp93) (§ 202):

> С прописной буквы пишутся местоимения *Вы*, *Ваш* как форма выражения
> вежливости при обращении к одному конкретному лицу в письмах,
> официальных документах и т. п., напр.: *Поздравляем Вас*... *Сообщаем
> Вам*... *В ответ на Ваш запрос*... Так же пишутся слова *Вы* и *Ваш* в
> текстах, предназначенных для многократного использования, типа анкет,
> реклам, листовок...